# Creating the same bootstrap sidebar menu that changes automatically when the div tag is hovered up?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, sidebar

I have been having some kind of trouble creating the kind of sidebar navigation menu that is found on the Twitter Bootstrap Documentation site, pls do help me, I need it for a clients project?

Comment: I recommend open the site in Google chrome, right click on the menu and select "Inspect Element". Then inspect the HTML/CSS from there and see how they did it. No one here can help you without seeing your code and a better description of what problems you are encountering.

Comment: What is the current code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is called Affix, and bootstrap includes it as a plugin. You just have to give it the appropriate class or via JS.

Here is some more info on it:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix